# How to create a build definition for ASP.NET 5 projects in TFS 2013 build server?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, build-definition, dnu

As we know that you need to use `dnu` to build an `ASP.NET 5` project, however `TFS 2013` doesn't know how to use `dnu`.

Is there a process in place to allow `TFS 2013` to build `ASP.NET 5`projects?

Can we for example replace the default command and supply our own in the build definition? if yes how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sul, to overcome the missing Microsoft.DNX.Props was not found issue:
You basically need to install Visual Studio Community version on the tfs server.  See this link:

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2373

After that you can work out the issue with the pre-build script to use DNU.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the dnu command in one PowerShell script, then add the PowerShell script in the Pre-build script in the build definition.

So, you need to
1). Create a PowerShell script file to include the due command, named PreBuild.ps1 for example. The PowerShell file is similar to the following (just give you a quick example, you need to do some changes based on your scenario) which is quoted from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5).
*Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }*

2). Include the PreBuild.ps1 in the build definition. 
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. So after the Pre-Build script run, what will happen? if the default behavior will kick in and runs MS Build against the project then that will fail? do we need to ignore that?

Also what about Unit tests? how can you run them as part of the build process?

Comment: 1). The called script file in the Pre-build script path runs before build starts, and the build will run successfully if all things work correct. 2). To run unit test in the build process, please go to  3.Tests -> Test Source -< specify the unit test project. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: I think I am missing something here. When you say the build will run after pre build script. What command is being used? do I need to care or because my pre build script already restored all the nuget packages then the build will just works regardless of what command it is using. My understanding is that MS Build will not build ASP.NET 5 projects because you need to use dnu. Is this not the case?

Comment: The pre-build script is called during the TFS build process, it is part of the build definition, you don't need to add any command tool to run it, just follow steps in my reply. You need to install DNX in the script. Check the Prebuild.ps1 in this MSDN article for the details:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5

Comment: I am getting this error: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Do I need to install something on the build server?